# multiple classes, same public interface

Tags: c++, oop, encapsulation

ok, after last night I've decided to rephrase my question for easier reading.
I have 2 classes, Army and Battle groups. heres the classes below, albeit with some parts missing:

```
class Battlegroups
{
    private: battlegroup battlegroupobject[100];

    public: 

    void AddBattleGroup(); //add a battlegroup object to the array
    void removebattlegroup(); //remove a battle group objects from the array
};

class Army
{
    private: battlegroups battlegroupsobject;

    public:

    void formbattlegroup()
    {
        battlegroupsobject.AddBattleGroup();
    }

    void disbandbattlegroup()
    {
        battlegroupsobject.removebattlegroup();
    }
};
```

See, the problem is the formbattlegroup() and the disbandbattlegroup(), which seems like its adding a pointless interface.

if there is a way for me to access the Addbattlegroup and removebattlegroup() methods without doing the above, please tell me.

or, tell me if this is the way you do it, but to me, it seems like adding code, for the sake of code.

Comment: The fact that the names of the functions differ seems to indicate that they are *different* in your design, even if the implementation of one is just dispatching to the other. In the future you might want to refactor and implement it somehow else... If they are the same in your design, why are the names different?

Comment: I made them different for clarity, but they pretty much do the same function

Comment: I think your call of making them different for clarity shows why it makes sense to give them different names. "Pretty much the same" has a different meaning to "semantically the same".   An interface should reflect usage; if the implementation of two functions are similar but their purpose differs then it makes sense to use different names to avoid confusion.   For example, a 'replace' function might be implemented pretty much the same as a 'find' function, but it wouldn't make sense to give them the same name.

Answer (score 2):

If `Battlegroups` is used only for containing objects, you may use `battlegroup battlegroupobject[100]` right in the `Army` instead. Or use `std::vector<battlegroup>`  instead of `battlegroups`. If not (and anyway), your decision seems quite correct, because there are different responsibilities of these objects.

Answer (score 0):

not very sure about your design, but here is my guess: you want to have `Army`, `Navy` etc. Then you may want to inherit `Army`, `Navy` from `Battlegroups`, such that you don't need to write `AddBattleGroup` and `RemoveBattleGroup` for every classes for `Army`, `Navy` etc . Like the following:

```
class Battlegroups
{
    // side-note: you may want to replaced below by std::vector<battlegroup>
    private: battlegroup battlegroupobject[100]; 

    public: 

    void AddBattleGroup(); 
    void RemoveBattleGroup(); 
};

class Army
 :  public Battlegroups
{
  // other specific implementations
};

class Navy
 :  public Battlegroups
{
  // other specific implementations
};

// usage
Army army1;
army1.AddBattleGroup();
Navy navy1;
navy1.AddBattleGroup();
```

If this is not what you want, you may want to consider Dmitry's answer.